# Animation goes away after applying geometry modifiers. How do I fix it?

Tags: animation, objects, geometry-nodes

[image: Scene time modifier aniamtion goes away after applying]

I am making a rotating ring of 3d leaves. Each Individual leaf rotates as well.

I used scene time to animate it, but when I apply the modifiers, the animation does not work.

I don't know what to do or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: that's totally "normal". Applying a geometry nodes modifier does not take animating into account. If you wanna have the animation, AFAIK you could use the alembic export which can handle that.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing nothing wrong. It is just that applying any modifier results in losing the functionality of modifying anything with it.

In your case you do not have a keyframed animation on some part of the object which is outside/independent of the *Geometry Nodes* modifier, so it cannot work anymore. Applying a modifier always creates a "snapshot" of the state the object is in when it gets applied (usually the state on the very frame you are on in this moment).

What you can do is (as @Chris already suggested) export the animation as an *Alembic (*.abc)* file. This creates (sorry for explaining this very simple) a mesh object with the animation as a cached sequence of mesh data, so basically storing for each vertex of the mesh where it has to be on each frame of the animation. If you have more objects in your scene but just want to export the animation of one object, make sure you check *Only* > *Selected Objects* in the export settings because it's disabled by default.

*Frame Start* and *End* are taken from your scene settings and do not necessarily correspond to your animation. That might be what you want when using the *Scene Time* node, but if you have for example an animation with a first keyframe on frame 10 and the last on frame 50, this range has to be set manually.

[image: export settings]

When you import an *Alembic* file into your scene, there is one import option enabled by default that might lead to unwanted results, so you maybe have to disable it. It is *Set Frame Range*, which means it will change your scene's *Start* and *End* setting to the ones in the imported file.

So, if you have exported an animation from frame 10 to frame 50 like in my example earlier, when you import it into a scene starting at frame 1 and ending at frame 250, these settings will be changed to 10 and 50 automatically. This can be annoying / confusing when you don't have it in mind, but you can simply set the scene back to the original values and even if there are other objects with keyframes outside the 10-50 range, they are of course not lost.

[image: import settings]

I guess there is a lot more to say or to learn about the use of *Alembic* animations, but this is not the place for tutorials and should just give you a hint on how you can preserve your *Geometry Nodes* animations. Some things could be manually rebuilt with setting keyframes for the rotation of the individual leaves if you separate them, but some animations are not that easily to recreate and especially not for a larger number of objects.

Comment: Thank you so much!